# Symfony-twig template form theme error

Tags: symfony, twig

I have everything working correctly and now I'm trying to work with form themes. This is my code to generate the form without a theme.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
{% include 'menu/menu.html.twig' %}
{% if addpost is defined %}
    <div id='add_post_form'>
        {{ form_start(addpost) }}
        {{ form_widget(addpost) }}
        {{ form_end(addpost) }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

But when I'm adding a form-theme with the following code

```
{% form_theme form 'form/form_div_layout.html.twig' %}
```

I get this error:

> Variable "form" does not exist

When i execute this without the line, I'm getting the following error:

> Unknown "form_help" function. Did you mean "form_rest", "form_end"?

the `form_div_layout.html.twig` contains the code found at [github symfony twig form theme](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig)

At my config.yml I've added the following under the `twig` section,

```
form_themes:
        - 'form/form_div_layout.html.twig'
```

.

either not, i still have this error
what is missing ???

---

My file structure

[image: My file structure]

Comment: Remove the theme from the config. It's not required, this way you make this theme global, to be used for every form. Unless you want to do that, if so you don't need the `form_theme` to be called.

Comment: Your form variable is 'addpost'.

Comment: Also note that with {% form_theme form _self %} the error still same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your forms are going to use the same theme you only need to add the line in your config, but if you want a particular form theme in a particular template you can use the template tag.

The reason you're getting the 'form is not defined error' is because you don't have a variable called form passed the the template, your form variable is called addpost, so you need to use

```
{% form_theme addpost 'form/form_div_layout.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: yes, i understood. Very nice and thank you. But now i take the second error. Unknown "form_help" function. Did you mean "form_rest", "form_end"? If you can help me, and let it be else story. I give you the correction

Comment: The form_help block should be defined and used in the form_div_layout file. Check you've actually got the complete file. If you're overriding it then check you're calling the parent properly.

Comment: what do you mean if i override it ? i just call it {% form_theme addpost 'form/form_div_layout.html.twig' %} . At the post i have the link of the twig file. Its from github. It must be correct

Comment: That's weird. Probably worth double checking that you've got all of the form_div_layout.html.twig file in case some got cut off. If you have have then it's probably a whole new question.